# How to fulfill ABC class definition of abstract properties in child class in Python

Tags: python, abstract-class

I have the following abc class:

```
class Logger(ABC):
    @abstractproperty
    def filename_prefix(self):
        pass

    @abstractproperty
    def trace_id_length(self):
        pass

    @abstractproperty
    def run_id_length(self):
        pass

    def __init__(self):
        self._load_history()

    def _load_history(self):
        try:
            with open(
                os.path.join(trace_history_dir, f"{self.filename_prefix}_history.json"),
                "r",
            ) as f:
                history = json.load(f)
        except Exception as e:
            if e.__class__.__name__ == "FileNotFoundError":
                history = {"0".zfill(self.trace_id_length): "Init"}

                with open(
                    os.path.join(
                        trace_history_dir, f"{self.filename_prefix}_history.json"
                    ),
                    "w",
                ) as f:
                    json.dumps(history)
            else:
                raise e

        return history
```

And the following child class:

```
class CostsLogger(Logger):
    def __init__(self):
        self.filename_prefix = filename_prefix
        self.trace_id_length = 4
        self.run_id_length = 4

        super.__init__()
```

The problem is that I'm getting this error when running:

`Can't instantiate abstract class CostsLogger with abstract methods filename_prefix, run_id_length, trace_id_length`

I don't want to force programmers to use `@property` when implementing a child class but keep the `@abstractporperty`'s in the abstract class definition to enforce their implementation, is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: so just require it in Logger `def __init__(self, filename_prefix, trace_id_length, run_id_length)` and assign to self?

Comment: Beside the point, but [`abstractproperty`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty) is deprecated.

Comment: You didn't define any *class* attributes named `filename_prefix`, etc, in order to fulfill the ABC contract. You only defined *instance* attributes.

Comment: *"I don't want to force programmers ... but ... enforce ..."* - That's contradictory. Maybe you're confusing properties and attributes? If you're coming from JS for example, the terminology is different.

Comment: @chepner abstract properties declared in abstract classes are an instruction for child classes to implement an instance property

Comment: @HuLu There's no such thing as an "instance property". Properties are defined on the class. I really think you have the concepts mixed up. If you need instance attributes to be defined, require them in `__init__`, like @Kamil said.